# How do I get XanMod kernels to show in up in grub boot menu on Debian 12?

Tags: debian, kernel, grub

I have installed the XanMod kernel sources list, per the directions on the XanMod site, on Debian 12 and then installed the latest XanMod kernel. I have also installed the grub-emu utility and when I run grub-emu the new Xanmod kernel shows up as an option.

When I reboot the machine, even after running `update-grub`, the XanMod kernel does not show up in the list of options.

Perhaps there is something about the Debian kernel management toolchain that I have missed? Or perhaps there's an issue with the XanMod kernel packages not invoking something it needs to invoke from Debian grub tool chain?

````
$ dpkg -l | egrep 'grub|xanmod' ; cat /etc/os-release 
ii  grub-common                                                 2.06-13+deb12u1                          amd64        GRand Unified Bootloader (common files)
ii  grub-efi-amd64                                              2.06-13+deb12u1                          amd64        GRand Unified Bootloader, version 2 (EFI-AMD64 version)
ii  grub-efi-amd64-bin                                          2.06-13+deb12u1                          amd64        GRand Unified Bootloader, version 2 (EFI-AMD64 modules)
ii  grub-efi-amd64-signed                                       1+2.06+13+deb12u1                        amd64        GRand Unified Bootloader, version 2 (amd64 UEFI signed by Debian)
ii  grub-emu                                                    2.06-13+deb12u1                          amd64        GRand Unified Bootloader, version 2 (emulated version)
ii  grub2-common                                                2.06-13+deb12u1                          amd64        GRand Unified Bootloader (common files for version 2)
ii  linux-headers-6.5.12-x64v3-xanmod1                          6.5.12-x64v3-xanmod1-0~20231120.g40a3b2e amd64        Linux kernel headers for 6.5.12-x64v3-xanmod1 on amd64
ii  linux-image-6.5.12-x64v3-xanmod1                            6.5.12-x64v3-xanmod1-0~20231120.g40a3b2e amd64        Linux kernel, version 6.5.12-x64v3-xanmod1
ii  linux-xanmod-x64v3                                          6.5.12-xanmod1-0                         amd64        Complete XanMod Linux kernel and headers [6.5] [x86-64-v3]              
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="12"
VERSION="12 (bookworm)"
VERSION_CODENAME=bookworm```
````

Comment: Turn of secure boot in uefi and try again please.